# Appium - Popup Alert message is not getting dismiss

Tags: java, android, ios, selenium, appium

I get an initial popup message As soon as i install the app and login for the first time Ex: Popup saying please turn on the locaiton from the settings, such kind of popup message and i get more than 2 of them.

I need to dismiss those and start using the app to automate other features, i dont need to click on it and accept them

I have used the below code:

```
capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
capabilities.setCapability("autoDismissAlerts", true);
```

But its not working, the popup are not dismissed. Those not throw any error,but the popup will not be dismissed

can some one help me on this.

I need to use this and get working on both Android and iOS
Using Java code

Comment: @yong.k Syntax please?

Answer (score 0):

Appium has problems dealing with native iOS alerts. Your problem is probably cause of a race condition between notification coming and auto accepting working. What you can try is adding a delay (like 5-10 seconds) for your test case for that particular screen and use an `accept()` in the next line. If that doesn't still work try using `touchActions` or try and find the dismiss button on screen.